# Locking selects

Tags: mysql, multithreading

I use InnoDB engine for all my tables. I know that by default INSERT creates lock for rows that will be inserted, and UPDATE creates lock for rows that it uses (no matter if in set or where clausules). SELECT doesn't lock anything. And nothing locks whole tables.

But what if I did something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file.txt'
```

If it would last 5min, anything could happen in some other thread. I've read I could use:

```
SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file.txt' LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

But then again I couldn't do any SELECT operations on this table, and it sucks.

What's the best approach to do this? Also, I've read that the last query should be used inside a transaction with a rollback instead of a commit - why is that so?

Comment: I believe you are wrong about not being able to "*do any SELECT operations on this table*".

Comment: 1) You *can* lock entire tables, using the [`LOCK TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/lock-tables.html) command—but it's a terrible idea, so don't do it.  2) `SELECT` will yield a view of the table at the moment execution began, and will not be affected by any writes that occur thereafter.  3) `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` does not block other read operations—it only blocks writes.

Comment: You can use the `FOR UPDATE` clause in `SELECT` to lock all the rows that were selected.

Comment: @eggyal: a consistent view of the table from the start of execution is guaranteed by the transaction **isolation level**. The default isolation level `REPEATABLE READ` gives a consistent view. But `READ UNCOMMITTED` doesn't.  [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html)

Comment: @spencer7593: That's referring to the view that is yielded by different `SELECT` statements within the same transaction; a single `SELECT` statement will never yield inconsistent table state.

Comment: @eggyal: The **`READ UNCOMMITTED`** isolation level does allow for reads of rows from earlier timepoints. Changes applied by other threads are visible, and those changes may later be rolled back, after the row has been read by the SELECT.The assertion that "a single `SELECT` will never yield inconsistent table state" may be comforting, but it isn't true when the SELECT is run `READ UNCOMMITTED`.

Comment: @spencer7593: It's still "a view of the table at the moment execution began" (to the extent that all the records in the resultset are internally consistent *with that viewpoint*), as I originally stated, but you're absolutely correct that the view itself could be dirty and inconsistent with committed state.  However, if the OP is using `READ UNCOMMITTED` then one presumes that is the desired behaviour? Still, I completely agree that my earlier statement was not entirely precise.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a consistent view of an InnoDB table for a long running SELECT, the best approach is to just ensure that the transaction isolation level for the session is set to `REPEATABLE READ` when the `SELECT` is run.

That won't block other threads that attempt to read the same rows. But it might block some threads from obtaining exclusive locks or write intent locks.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html

---

As an addendum, to clarify some of the points OP raises.

*"SELECT doesn't lock anything."*

It's true that a non-locking `SELECT` won't obtain row locks. But some special SELECT statements (as pointed out later) that can obtain row locks:

```
  SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
  SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE
```

And there are meta-data locks, which will block DDL operations on the table (e.g. `ALTER TABLE`) while the `SELECT` statement is executing.

*"And nothing locks whole tables."*

That's not strictly true.  A `LOCK TABLE` statement can obtain a lock on the entire table. And a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` (with no predicates) could (potentially) obtain locks on every row in the table.

*"SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE will block other SELECT statements"*

This isn't true. Shared locks will block exclusive locks from other threads. But they won't block other threads from obtaining share locks, and won't block non-locking SELECT statements.

*What's the best approach to do this?*

To re-iterate the first part of my answer again... just run a non-locking SELECT statement. As long as the transaction isolation level isn't set to `READ UNCOMMITED`, the SELECT statement will get a consistent view of the rows in the table, from the timepoint at the time the SELECT begins executing.

*Also, I've read that the last query should be used inside a transaction with a rollback instead of a commit - why is that so?*

This is a curious notion. It has me puzzled. Why would a `ROLLBACK` preferred over a `COMMIT`?

As long as no DML changes have been applied, I think the `COMMIT` and the `ROLLBACK` would be equivalent. In both cases, all of the locks obtained by the transaction would be released. In terms of the database, I don't think it makes a difference.

This has me thinking this recommendation comes from a preferred pattern on the client side. Maybe there's a notion of following a rule such as *"don't commit unless you've applied DML changes"*.  But that's just a guess.

My personal recommendation would be to follow the normative pattern of using a `COMMIT` to end the transaction. I don't favor using an implicit `ROLLBACK`. In my personal opinion, a `ROLLBACK` should be issued when we want to explicitly discard DML changes that have been applied in a transaction. And that's typically due to an exception or error condition.